# Elasticsearch with nodejs - I just want to print my query in the console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, elasticsearch

Is there any way to print the elasticsearch query in the log while using nodejs?

```
client.search({
  index: 'my-index',
  query: { match_all: {} }
}
```

In above code I just need the index and query form the body. More specifically I am concerned about query parameters.

I didn't find anything useful with google.

Comment: @mplungjan The question is regarding printing to console rather than writing to a file.

Comment: @mplungjan just want to print the query on console

Comment: @mplungjan It's in the question - "Elasticsearch with nodejs - I just want to print my query in the console"

Comment: I am still trying to help. Why can't you do `let searchObject= { index: 'my-index', query: { match_all: {} } }; console.log(query); client.search(searchObject); ` ?

Comment: Well thats all what I required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the event emitter interface:

```
 const { events } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
 console.log(events)
```

For implementation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/observability.html

Comment: @mplungjan its only giving meta information. I need to print whatever is in the body of client.search i.e contents of search body or criteria of the query on which i am searching. 
client.search({
  index: 'my-index',
  query: { match_all: {} }
}

In this case I need index and query from the body

Comment: Oops! Sorry, I thought it was yours.